# Grabbing images from a DVD using direct show

Tags: c++, directshow

Is anybody aware of a way of grabbing images from a DVD using DirectShow and C++?  The sample grabber is not supported when using the DVD renderer and if I use GetCurrentImage, which is part of the VMR9 windoless control, it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "SampVid" sample in the directshow samples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375468(VS.85).aspx

With that you can write your own video renderer filter.  The only issue you'll have is how to capture the frmae as it all goes through "[CDrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374413%28VS.85%29.aspx)" class.  The source code to which is contained in winutil.h &.cpp which are included in the direct show base classes.  Rolling your own version would solve your issue and allow you to grab a frame of image data as it is being written to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the input, will look into that.  Not sure how effective this will be with a DVD though but will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Write a trans-in-place video filter, which you can use to grab a sample and write it to disk.

When you detect a keypress (for screenshot), call a callback into your program from the filters' Transform() function.

Have a look at MSDN's guide on [Writing Transform Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391015%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information on writing filters.

You could check out the [EZRGB24 filter sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375634%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from MSDN, which demonstrates how to use the CTransformFilter

Good luck!